# How to derive the log posterior probability of bayes classifier?

Tags: bayesian, classification

Looking at the [Introduction to Statistical Learning book](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf) in equation 4.13 it mentions the log posterior probability as :

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k )   $$

And the book says:

> Taking the log of (4.12) and rearranging the terms, it is not hard to
>   show that this is equivalent to [above]

The equation 4.12 is

$$ p_k(x) = \frac {\pi_k \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma}  exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_k)^2 \right)  }   {\sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right)}    $$

I am asking about the steps to take the log of equation 4.12 and reach equation 4.13.

---

Update: 
I have tried to do the following steps but I am not sure about the correctness of the reasoning, especially about the last transformation.

Take the log on both sides

$$ \delta_k(x) = log \left(  \frac {\pi_k \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma}  exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_k)^2 \right)  } 
{\sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right)} \right) 
$$

Use some log properties  $log(A/B) = log(A) - log(B)$

$$ \delta_k(x) = log \left(  \pi_k \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma}  exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_k)^2 \right)  \right)  
 -  log \left( \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right) \right) 
$$

Use some more log properties $log(A*B) = log(A) + log(B),  log(e^k) = k$

$$
\delta_k(x) = log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_k)^2    
- log \left( \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right) \right) 
$$

Open up the square

$$ \delta_k(x) = log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac {x^2 - 2x\mu_k+\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}   
 - log \left( \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right) \right) $$

Write the terms of the fraction separately.

$$\delta_k(x) = log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{x\mu_k}{\sigma^2} -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}   
 - log \left( \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right) \right) $$

Reorder some terms so that the desired terms are the first 3 operands

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}  
 - log \left( \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right) \right) $$

The first 3 terms are already the desired outcome. Now re-arrange the rest.

The $ \frac{1}{sqrt(2\pi) \sigma}$ is independent of the summation index. Take that out of the summation.

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}  
 - log \left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l exp \left( - \frac {1}{2\sigma^2} (x- \mu_l)^2 \right) \right) $$

Also expand the exponent.

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}  
 - log \left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l  exp \left( - \frac {x^2 - 2 x\mu_l + \mu_l^2 }{2\sigma^2}  \right) \right) $$

Split the exponent term into two

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}  
 - log \left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l exp \left( - \frac { x^2  }{2\sigma^2}  \right)  exp \left( \frac { 2 x\mu_l - \mu_l^2 }{2\sigma^2}  \right) \right) $$

The separated out exponent term is also independent of the summation variable $l$. So take that also out of the summation.

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}  
 - log \left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left( - \frac { x^2  }{2\sigma^2}  \right) \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l   exp \left( \frac { 2 x\mu_l - \mu_l^2 }{2\sigma^2}  \right) \right) $$

Use the log properties for multiplication and exponentiation

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k ) + log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}  
- log( \frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma} )  + \frac { x^2  }{2\sigma^2} 
 - log \left(  \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l   exp \left( \frac { 2 x\mu_l - \mu_l^2 }{2\sigma^2}  \right) \right)
 $$

The terms in the middle cancel eachother out

$$ \delta_k(x) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}  -  \frac {\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2}    +  log  ( \pi_k )
 - log \left(  \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l   exp \left( \frac { 2 x\mu_l - \mu_l^2 }{2\sigma^2}  \right) \right) $$

So the last term in the $log$ is a summation over all classes. In bayes classification we are going to choose the class (k) that has the largest $\delta_k(x)$ for a given x. The last term in $log$ would be the same for each $\delta_k$ so it does not matter and effectively can be dropped.

Hence we get our log posterior probability in equation 4.13

Comment: This is a correct reasoning, although you could have stopped earlier by excluding terms not depending on the index $k$.